# How to search inside a List<String> inside an abstract data type as attribute of other Abstract Data Type using the Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Library class that uses Set copies as a field.
This BookCopy has as attributes Book book and Condition c.
The Book class has String title, int year and List authors.
I'm implementing a method (using Streams) to search for title or authors using a string:

```
public List<Book> find(String query) {

    Set<BookCopy> allCopies = this.copies;
    //Set<BookCopy> becomes Set<Book> with only matching title books 
    Set<Book> booksByTitle = allCopies
            .stream()
            .map(BookCopy::getBook)
            .filter(b -> b.getTitle().contains(query))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    //Set<BookCopy> becomes Set<Book> with only matching authors books
    Set<Book> booksByAuthor = allCopies
            .stream()
            .map(BookCopy::getBook)
            .filter(b -> {
                for (String s:b.getAuthors()){
                    s.contains(query);
                }})
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    booksByTitle.addAll(booksByAuthor);

    return new ArrayList<>(booksByTitle);
    }
```

The BooksByTitle seems to be fine, however for BooksByAuthor the IDE throws an error saying:

**( no type b) -> {} isn't applicable**

How can I filter that Set so only books in which the authors list matches the query are passed?
Sorry about the crappy code, I'm just trying to make it work first and I'm just learning about Java stream API, and Java 8 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really look into **anyMatch**, as you are interested in only those books that have at least one author that you are interested in.

```
  .stream()
  .map(BookCopy::getBook)
  .filter(b -> b.authors.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.contains(query)))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: I think anyMatch is what I was looking for. I replace equals with contains since query could be a substring of the author String. Id do some testing later to verify

Comment: Of course, it should be `contains` instead of `equals`. If the task was not a substring search but equality, a simple `.filter(b -> b.authors.contains(query))` was sufficient. For larger numbers (of books, of authors, or string lengths) it might be more efficient to prepare the search: `Predicate<String> queryP = Pattern.compile(query, Pattern.LITERAL).asPredicate();` and use it like `.filter(b -> b.authors().stream().anyMatch(queryP))`. This enables optimized searches, e.g. using the Boyer Moore algorithm…

Comment: @Holger yes contains, it was type, corrected. Now the reference to the pattern and Boyer Moore makes a lot of sense. as usual, a big thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your second filter is missing a (`boolean`) return statement.

Your first filter is working because it contains only one line, of which the last method call returns a `boolean`, which is implicitly returned.

Change your second filter to:

```
            filter(b -> {
                for (String s:b.getAuthors()){
                    if(s.contains(query)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
              })
```

In order to properly return a `boolean` which will be used for the filtering.

Comment: Great! I thought that since s.contains(query) was boolean, it would return true automatically and false wasn't required.

Comment: That would not work because the line is inside a loop. The compiler can not deduce the logic you want to apply - do you want to return true if **at least one** string contains the query (as it is now)? Or do you want to return true only if **all** strings contain the query? Or something completely different? You have to specify that manually.

Comment: The idea is that if the String query matches ('equal to' or as 'substring of') one of strings in the List<String> authors attribute from Book, then that Book should be in the List<Book>, otherwise discarded.